# How to overcome variable scope issues with functions in php?

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

I am creating an engineering type website that does lots of calculations on mechanical parts.  I use functions but I have about 75 global variables that are continuously used by many functions. Declaring them as global inside each function, or alternatively passing so many to each function, creates the very spaghetti code I am trying to solve by using functions. Is there a way to make a truly global variable in PHP like other languages? Or a simple subroutine? Or is there a better programming construct I should learn?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**.

PHP requires explicit export of the global scope into local function scope. That's actually a benefit, in my opinion. If you rely on global scope by default you're using functions wrong. Functional programming is intended to obviate side effects (i.e. state). By requiring a function to observe global state you are by definition creating [Spooky Action at a Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance). Not at all a desirable thing. This will make you both reading and debugging your code a nightmare.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that this may be a misuse of functions. But passing 50 variables to a function or declaring them repetitively in a dozen functions creates the reading and debugging nightmare you mentioned to avoid. Other languages would have a subroutine.  Is there an equivalent to a subroutine in PHP? Just a block of code that can be called with program flow returning when complete? Or have I made a poor choice of languages for this type of application?

Comment: If you find that your function needs that many variables one of two things has gone horribly wrong. Either you aren't using arrays the way you should or your  function is doing way too much. No, there is no concept of subroutines the way you're thinking in PHP.

Comment: A function doing too much suggests to break it into multiple functions which exacerbates the problem as it increases the global declarations.  Maybe your suggestion of using arrays better is where I should be investigating.

Comment: I never suggested that you continue to use globals in the first place. My ONLY suggestion is that you simplify the behavior you're writing, such that you would inherently simplify the number of variables needed in each function, such that you would inherently simplify the state concerned in each local scope, such that you inherently **obviate** all global state. :-) Cheers!

Comment: If you've got a bunch of closely related functions that all need the same data (or substantial subsets of it), what you probably want is to create a class that holds all of that data and provides functions that operate on it.

Comment: Yes, that describes the problem well - a bunch of closely related functions that need the same data.  I will learn a bit about classes (and OOP). Thanks.